# How to create Block References in dxf files using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, ogr, dxf, autocad

I need to use GDAL to create dxf files in AutoCAD. I have already implemented the creation of point-line geometry layers and label layers, but now the creation of Block References keeps failing. In the official [GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html#vector-dxf), I found that it supports the creation of Block References.

[image]

First, configure `DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS=FALSE`, where I don't know how to assign the relevant parameter settings：`BlockName`,`BlockScale`, `BlockAngle`, `BlockOCSNormal`, `BlockOCSCoords`, `BlockAttributes`, `Block`. In the CAD layers with Block References, I found with the properties `BlockScale`, `BlockOCSCoords`. The others do not know how to set.

[image]

This is the shape of the Block References.

[image]

This is my java code.

```java
Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("DXF");
DataSource dataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(path);
Layer blockLayer = dataSource.CreateLayer("blocks");
```

...

```java
public void AddBlockFeature(String name, String blockName, String style, long fid, String geom){
    Feature feature = new Feature(blockLayer.GetLayerDefn());
    // FID
    feature.SetFID(fid);
    feature.SetField("Layer", name);
    // set Block
    feature.SetField("Block", name);
    //set BlockName
    feature.SetField("BlockName", blockName);
    //set BlockScale
    feature.SetField("BlockScale", "[0.5,0.5,0.5]");
    // geometry  WKT 
    Geometry geometry = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(geom);
    feature.SetGeometry(geometry);
    //set xyz
    String xyz = String.format("[%f,%f,%f]", geometry.GetX(), geometry.GetY(), 0.0);
    feature.SetField("BlockOCSCoords", xyz);
    //set style
    feature.SetStyleString(style);
    // layer add feature
    blockLayer.CreateFeature(feature);
}
```

I found that SYMBOL is provided in the [Feature Style Specification](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_feature_style.html) of GDAL, and I don't know if it can be achieved through style.